# TFS too many characters when 'getting'

Tags: tfs

I'm attempting to map a TFS directory to a local directory. The problem is that as it's getting - a .datasource's filename is too large to be saved locally. I had a little look around and found [this page](http://praphullaparab.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/tfs-2010-error-tf205022-path-contains-more-than-the-allowed-259-characters/) - which implies that it wouldn't matter to get rid of this file. I'd rather not delete it from TFS so can I safely assume that even though I have been given the error - all of the files that were due to be got before and after the datasource file are safely mapped now or will TFS stop getting at the point at which it comes across this error??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try mapping to a folder near the root, perhaps with a short name. Try mapping to `C:\A` and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: That's done the trick John thanks. Still - it seems like a bit of a work around this.

Comment: You're "working around" the Windows file system. It has nothing to do with TFS.

Comment: I didn't imply I was working around an issue with TFS. Nevertheless, I don't like the idea that I have very little choice of what directory I can map to this repository because of a character restraint. I'm going to look into options of renaming the file or simply ignoring the error as it's apparently not needed anyway. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You are right you can fix this by create a drive on your computer with the path that you want, see the following link http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/how-to-fix-the-path-cant-be-more-than-260-character-error-in-tfs/

Comment: Thanks Mohamed!! Very handy tip!